# Windows Explorer Advanced Search

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, search, windows-search

I have a question on windows advanced search, I am running Windows 8.1 pro. I want to exclude a particular file type from showing up in the search results and I tried following [these instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows) but I can't seem to get it to work. The exact search query I put in was:

```
size:<1024mb AND type:<>.rar
```

So I should be getting back all the files that are less than 1GB but are **NOT** .rar files. The website said `<>` means *is not* so I don't get why my query does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

To filter results by file extension you can use `ext` or `fileext` in English locales. For example:

```
size:<1024mb AND ext:<>.rar
```

The following query would work regardless of the installed locale:

```
System.Size:<1024mb AND System.FileExtension:<>.rar
```

**Note** While the syntax is not case-sensitive, you need to type the `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` operators in all capital letters.

### Further reading

- [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Windows Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)